# count how many elements are exist within the same CLASS_NAME in the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm currently writing a UI test for creating a new message in my app, I ran into an issue with asserting that the message is actually created.
The assertion I want to make contain two stages, First, counting the current amount of messages in the page(all the messages got the same CLASS_NAME) before the new message is created.
Second, count the amount of messages after the new message has been created and expect a +1 difference in the count.
I'm stuck on the first stage.

---

Example **HTML Document**

```html
<div data-v-33228p9f="" data-v-44788nw1="" class="status-card status-card-rejected">
<div data-v-34524d1n="" class="card-header">
<div data-v-7895hewq="" class="card-title">
<div data-v-rs39lmno="" class="card-title-text">
<div data-v-3w9f8wsa="" data-v-3746955y="" class="tooltip" tooltip="message header" position="top">
```

Python Selenium implementation

```
    currentAmountOfMessages = len((driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-title')))
    print('current amount of messages is:')
    print (currentAmountOfMessages)
```

The outcome received is

```
current amount of messages is:
0
```

Because I received the value 0 - I wondered maybe the code is correct but the class_name isn't but I've tried all the class names which belong to the messages in my app and none of them worked.

Comment: could you please attach the html document where you search for?

Comment: @bigmauri
<div data-v-33228p9f="" data-v-44788nw1="" class="status-card status-card-rejected"><div data-v-34524d1n="" class="card-header"><div data-v-7895hewq="" class="card-title"><div data-v-rs39lmno="" class="card-title-text"><div data-v-3w9f8wsa="" data-v-3746955y="" class="tooltip" tooltip="message header" position="top">

unfortunately I can't share the full html document so I sent part of the relevant block

Comment: as per [official doc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_id-driver-method-selenium-python/) is driver.find_element(), are there any typos in your python code?

Comment: @bigmauri using element instead of elements leads to error in locating the element
can't see any typo

EDIT- managed to solve it, thanks